# Need assistance for converting js code to php

Tags: javascript, php, binary, filereader

I try to convert JavaScript code to PHP. Code parse binary file.

I open file, move pointer to the beginning, read bytes.

```
$file = fopen($filePath, 'rb');
if ($file) {
    rewind($file);
    $buffer = fread($file, 126273);
}
```

So I have string in `$buffer`. Then I try to unpack it using

```
$unpacked = unpack('N', $buffer);
```

I get `unsigned long (always 32 bit, big endian byte order)`. This is equal to JavaScript `buffer.readUInt32BE()` (I think... I receive the same values)

Then I need to convert another string, but with offset.

JavaScript code:

```
buffer.readUInt32BE(offset)
```

On PHP i tried do somthing like

```
unpack('N', substr($buffer, $offset))
```

But I got different values.

Could yo explain to me how to do it using php?

Comment: Maybe PHP is messing with UTF8 in the binary data. Try with unpack('N', substr($buffer, $offset,'8bit')) to ensure every character is treated as 1 byte and ignore null terminators ('\0').

Comment: @JoseLuisBernat, thank you for reply, but it didnt help

Comment: Using GoLang i do something like `binary.BigEndian.Uint32(buffer[offset:])`